# Laravel 5 blank page view

Tags: laravel-5, view

Started working through a very basic Laravel 5 tuturial, after installing a thresh laravel installation via composer, and experienced the following problem. Having created an about view 'resources/views/about.blade.php', I only get a blank page displayed.

The strange thing is, having played around with the welcome page, to try and isolate the problem, it turns out that I can only view the welcome page if its name is welcome.

routes.php code:

```
Route::get('about', 'PagesController@about');
```

PagesController.php code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class PagesController extends Controller {

    public function about() {
        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

This displays the 'resources/views/welcome.blade.php' file prefectly. However, if I rename it to anything else eg. 'resources/views/test.blade.php', and change the return view in the controller accordingly:

```
return view('test');
```

I just get a blank page. What's the problem?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Try to clear the cache, ``php artisan view:clear`` This is for Laravel 5.1 if you use 5 then you could try ``php artisan cache:clear``

Comment: Clearing cache has not fixed the problem.

Comment: @user2417713 Do you have a 500 error in your browser inspector?

Comment: There's no error message, just a blank white page.

Comment: Set APP_DEBUG to true in .env file & check log files in storage/log directory for error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turns out to be the URL. Following the Laracast tutorials (Laravel 5 Fundamentals), I started the server using the following command:

```
php -S localhost:8888 -t ~/Desktop/html/learning-laravel-5/public
```

This results in the following Laravel project's root address: http://localhost:8888

Consequently, http://localhost:8888/about equates to the about page. However, I ended up using the following address:

```
localhost/learning-laravel-5/public/about
```

This results in a blank page if I haven't already viewed the page via http://localhost:8888/about

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problems should be this,

**Problem :**

You would not configured your `.htaccess` to point your application directly

**What should you do**

You should make your call to the application absolutely

**How**

Do you call like this

```
http://yourapplication.com/public/index.php/about
```

If you want to access it like

```
http://yourapplication.com/about
```

then you should configure `.htaccess` to make it done (Let me know if you need this)

**Note :**

1. Make sure that you enable error_reporting in your server
2. Make sure that you output something in your blade